# In Python, can you change how a method from class 1 acts on class 2 from within class 2?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy, subclass

Basically I have a class which subclasses ndarray and has additional information. When I call np.asarray() on my object, it returns just the numpy array and destroys my additional information.

My question is then this: Is there a way in Python to change how np.asarray() acts on my subclass of ndarray from within my subclass? I don't want to change numpy of course, and I do not want to go through every instance where np.asarray() is called to take care of this.

Thanks in advance!

Chris

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner if you wrote a ``as_myspecialarray()`` function?

Comment: The point is that I am using a large codebase, which I don't want to change specifically for what I am doing now. I could do that but then I would need to change a lot of code. I was hoping to fix the problem from my end, so the public code is not affected. Thanks.

Comment: Study the `np.matrix` or `np.ma.masked` code to see how those array sub classes retain control.

Comment: Are you familiar with the numpy subclassing documentation? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. Numpy's `asarray()` doesn't check e.g. if a special method on the class of its argument exists and so doesn't provide a way to override its behaviour.

Long answer: It's not possible from your subclass, but you can hotpatch the numpy module in your module level code to replace the asarray function with your own wrapper. This is a very hacky solution and I don't recommend it, but it may work for you.

```
_real_asarray = np.asarray
def _new_asarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):
  if isinstance(a, MyClass):
    # special handling here
  else:
    return _real_asarray(a, dtype, order)
np.asarray = _new_asarray
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try your code and see how it goes. Can I ask why you do not recommend it though?

Comment: Because it fiddles in the namespace of another module. After running your code everything that calls `np.asarray()` in the same interpreter session will call your replacement function instead of the original function. Others reading your code (and probably yourself in a few months) won't expect `np.asarray` to behave different after your module executed. If your function returns wrong results it may take hours before realizing that `np.asarray` isn't the usual `np.asarray`.

Comment: `np.asanyarray` passes subclasses through.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Numpy's `asarray()` is coded to instantiate a regular numpy array, and you can't change that without editing `asarray()` or changing the caller's code to call your special method instead of `asarray()`